# Consider the function $f(x) = x^2 + 4/x^2$ a) Find$f ^\prime(x)$ b) Find the values of $x$ at which the tangent to the curve is horizontal.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So far I have this...

a) $f^\prime(x) = 2x + (0)(x^2)-(4)\dfrac{2x}{(x^2)^2}$

$= 2x - \dfrac{8x}{x^4}$

$= \dfrac{2x^5 - 8x}{x^4}$

$= \dfrac{2(x^4 - 4)}{x^3}$

I believe I derived this correctly.

But i am not sure how to do part b). I know the horizontal slope $= 0$ but when i solve it i get $2(x^4 - 4)$ and don't know how to go from there.

`

Comment: Good work so far. We know that the tangent is horizontal whenever the slope is 0. We also know that the slope is $2(x^4 - 4)/x^3$. Therefore, the tangent is horizontal whenever $2(x^4 - 4)/x^3 = 0$. What do you get when you solve the equation $2(x^4 - 4)/x^3 = 0$?

Comment: 2(x^4 -4). Now from this the x values would be sqrt +2 and sort -2 but since we can't sqrt -2 would the answer be x = +/- sqrt 2?

Comment: To solve $x^4=4$, note maybe that $x^2=2$ (since a square cannot be $-2$), so $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: right, so the x values would be x = +/- sort 2. would another x value also be 0 because we have a 2 <-- (x^4 - 4)?

Comment: No, because $x = 0$ is not a solution to the equation $2(x^4 - 4)/x^3 = 0$. In fact, $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 0$, because you would have to divide by 0 to calculate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivative is correct. You could have saved yourself some work by using the power rule.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^2 + \frac{4}{x^2}\\
     & = x^2 + 4x^{-2}
\end{align*}
Using the power rule yields
\begin{align*}
f'(x) & = 2x^1 - 2 \cdot 4x^{-3}\\
      & = 2x - 8x^{-3}\\
      & = 2x - \frac{8}{x^3}
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to your expression
$$f'(x) = \frac{2(x^4 - 4)}{x^3}$$
To find the values of $x$ at which the tangent line is horizontal, set $f'(x) = 0$, which yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{2(x^4 - 4)}{x^3} & = 0\\
2(x^4 - 4) & = 0\\
x^4 - 4 & = 0\\
(x^2)^2 - 2^2 & = 0\\
(x^2 + 2)(x^2 - 2) & = 0\\
\end{align*}
Setting each factor equal to zero yields
\begin{align*}
x^2 + 2 & = 0 & x^2 - 2 & = 0\\
x^2 & = -2 & x^2 & = 2\\
x & = \pm i\sqrt{2} & x & = \pm\sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
Since there can only be a tangent at real values of $x$, we conclude that the only horizontal tangents of the graph occur at $x = \pm\sqrt{2}$.